# Java IP Address,MAC address return with name of device

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

I am trying to code in android to return the name of all devices and their ip on the wifi. I am having trouble on how to approach this. All of the examples online return only the localhost and its information. i.e.

```
 try {
            InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println(" IP Addr: " + localhost.getHostAddress());
            // Just in case this host has multiple IP addresses....
            InetAddress[] allMyIps = InetAddress.getAllByName(localhost.getCanonicalHostName());
            if (allMyIps != null && allMyIps.length > 1) {
                System.out.println(" Full list of IP addresses:");
                for (int i = 0; i < allMyIps.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("    " + allMyIps[i]);
                }
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println(" (error retrieving server host name)");
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("Full list of Network Interfaces:");
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                System.out.println("    " + intf.getName() + " " + intf.getDisplayName());
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                    System.out.println("        " + enumIpAddr.nextElement().toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            System.out.println(" (error retrieving network interface list)");
        }
```

This is not necessarily What I want, since I want to return all of the devices on the wifi.

I don't know how to go about this. 
please help, thank you !

Comment: I don't get it.  Why do you include a bunch of irrelevant code that solves a different problem to the one you are trying to solve?

Comment: I was trying to post an example of what I have been trying out which hasn't been working

Comment: Well obviously.  We want you to post code that shows something that is actually relevant to the problem.  Posting code that you know to be irrelevant and that you "found on the internet"  is not evidence of a **genuine attempt** at trying to the solve the problem yourself ... is it.

Comment: Im sorry, but I didn't know how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

**WifiManager** This class provides the primary API for managing all aspects of Wi-Fi connectivity. Get an instance of this class by calling `Context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)`. It deals with several categories of items:

1. The list of configured networks. The list can be viewed and updated, and attributes of individual entries can be modified.
2. The currently active Wi-Fi network, if any. Connectivity can be established or torn down, and dynamic information about the state of the network can be queried.
3. Results of access point scans, containing enough information to make decisions about what access point to connect to.
4. It defines the names of various Intent actions that are broadcast upon any sort of change in Wi-Fi state.

**WifiInfo** Describes the state of any Wifi connection that is active or is in the process of being set up.

**Example:**

```
WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
String ipAddress = Formatter.formatIpAddress(ip);
String macAddress = wifiInfo.getMacAddress();
```

Ensure you have modified your manifest with the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

**Sources:**
1. [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html)
2. [WifiInfo API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html)

Comment: I don't thinks this solves the problem.  The OP wants to find devices not networks.

Comment: I see. Agree. He is keen to find the devices in the network and then the adresses. I am fine with the dupe message you have pointed out.